# Criteria for "Contain Encryption" restriction for App Store approval

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

When submitting an app that contains cryptography, I know there's a checkbox you must check, as well as subsequent questionnaire you must answer. And if the app contains cryptography you need to go through complex Exporter Registration and Reporting process.

There are three specific cases I'm curious about:

### 1. Cryptocurrency wallets

One of the "exemption" clause says:

> (ii) your app uses, accesses, implements or incorporates encryption for authentication only

Does this exempt the app from having to go through all the complicated government approval process? Most cryptocurrency wallets only use cryptography for signatures and authentication, but I'm not sure how this applies to this case.

Simply put, do all Bitcoin wallet app developers have to get government approval before submitting the app?

### 2. End-to-End encrypted messaging apps

How about end-to-end encrypted chat apps? Do I have to go through the approval process?

I'm talking apps like Signal and whatsapp.

### 3. Does WKWebView + Webcrypto count?

What if I'm using WKWebView which contains access to webcrypto API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Crypto_API inside the app, does this count as "contain encryption"?

Answer (score 0):

From [Apple FAQ](https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/apps/faq/Managing%20Your%20Apps_Export%20Compliance#93377577):

> Use of encryption includes, but is not limited to:
>
> - Making calls over secure channels (i.e. HTTPS, SSL, and so on)
> - Using standard encryption algorithms
> - Using crypto functionality from other sources such as iOS or macOS
> - Using proprietary or non-standard encryption algorithms

You didn't specify source of your "exemption", but I guess it is not from Apple guidelines.

I would say that your cases are using encryption or crypto so are in scope of this guidelines.

I found some more informations [here](https://medium.com/@cossacklabs/apple-export-regulations-on-crypto-6306380682e1) - maybe will help you.